# Rewriting query to move subquery out of FROM clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have an `entries` table that looks something like this:

```
| id | category | text | user_id |
|----|----------|------|---------|
| 1  | A        | z    | 22      |
| 2  | B        | y    | 23      |
| 3  | B        | x    | 24      |
| 4  | C        | w    | 25      |
```

*id is unique; none of the other columns are*

I want to get the row for specified category(ies) that have the highest ID.  So in this example if I'm search for category `B` I'd expect it to return `3,B,x,24`

There are several more columns in the table, but only those three are shown for brevity.  Other columns exist which have to be joined, e.g. to get user info.

I have the following query, which works:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT MAX(id) as id
         FROM entries
         WHERE category = 'B'
         GROUP BY category
     ) as tmp
         LEFT JOIN entries e ON e.id = tmp.id
         LEFT JOIN users u ON (e.user_id = u.id)
```

An `OR` condition can be added to the WHERE clause when I need to select multiple categories, and that works.

However my ORM doesn't support subqueries in the FROM clause.  I managed to get it to work with WHERE ANY, but the query is 4.5 times slower:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE id = ANY 
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) as id
        FROM entries
        WHERE category = 'B'
        GROUP BY category
    );
```

Replacing ANY with ALL yields the same data but ALL takes at least 5 times longer than ANY.

Is there another syntax that runs as fast as the first but with some other syntax?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM entries
WHERE category = 'B'
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This doesn't work; the post mentions that multiple categories need to be selected so a GROUP BY is necessary, and the ORDER BY happens after the GROUP BY, and therefore the highest entry for each category will not be returned

Comment: @user218609 If so provide adequate sample data which demonstrates all possible facts combination and desired result for it. The best way - provide online fiddle with this data.

Comment: All the information needed is contained in the question.  If you need clarifications, add a comment to the question

Comment: @user218609 *All the information needed is contained in the question.* My query fully matches your source data and desired output provided in a question. If you are not glad then your information is partial.

Comment: READ THE QUESTION and you will see "I need to select multiple categories".  Your query does not work.  Your answer is wrong.  We all make mistakes, the only difference is whether or not you can admit them.  And you can't.

Comment: @user218609 This everything means that you provide non-adequate sample data. Expand it until the wrongness become visible at least.